# Using Query Builder to execute multiple WhereExists

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Here is the relevant part of the ERD:

[image: ERD]

- Post is an ad of a computer or laptop.
- A computer or laptop contains several parts (processor, memory, storage etc). A Postpart represents one such part.
- A component is particular model of hardware, e.g. Intel Core i9 (9th gen) or Samsung 970 Evo Plus.
- Since each component has their own set of attributes, we have created a polymorphic relation between processors, memories, (storage, keyboard and several other components types not shown in the diagram)

Now I need to search for all the posts that comply with the following conditions.

- Have one or more of the specified words in `title` or `description`
- Have got a processor with `core_clock` between `1.8` and `2.4` GHz.
- Have got a **total memory** of `32` GB or more. (i.e. we need to sum up memories of each post)

In the good old SQL world, we could probably do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p WHERE title LIKE `%Acer Aspire%` AND description LIKE `%something else%`
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT id FROM components c 
   INNER JOIN processors pr ON c.componentable_id = pr.id
   INNER JOIN postparts pp ON p.id = pp.post_id
   WHERE pr.core_clock BETWEEN 1.8 AND 2.4
)
AND 
(
   (SELECT SUM(total) FROM components c 
   INNER JOIN memories m ON c.componentable_id = m.id
   INNER JOIN postparts pp ON p.id = pp.post_id) >= 32
)
...
```

and continue like that for all other components. Now I'm trying to achieve that using Eloquent or Query Builder. Here is what I have written so far:

```
$query = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%')->
         orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%');

$query = $query->whereExists(
           function ($query) {
             $query->select("1")->from('postparts')->
             join('components', 'postparts.component_id', '=', 'component.id')->
             join('processors', 'processors.id', '=', 'component.componentable_id')->
             where('postparts.post_id', 'posts.id')->
             where('processors.core_clock', '>=', 1.8)->
             where('processors.core_clock', '<=', 2.4);
           });

$query = $query->where(
             function ($query) {
               $query->join('postparts', 'postparts.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')->
               join('components', 'postparts.component_id', '=', 'component.id')->
               join('memories', 'memories.id', '=', 'component.componentable_id')->
               sum('total') >= 32;
         });
```

This doesn't work and complains about `access violation or syntax error` in the query. What am I doing wrong here?

N.B. I also have setup polymorphic relationship between the Laravel models and can successfully fetch all (polymorphic) components of a single `Post` using `Post::with('Postparts.Component')->find($post_id)`. However I'm not sure if Eloquent will really be as efficient as Query Builder or a raw query. If it is, how can I filter `Posts` based on polymorphic child models without actually fetching them into a collection?

Comment: If you doubt what the query is going to look like, you can add `->toSql()` at the ending of any query. Remember that it will return a string with the actual query that will be executed, so do not call `->get()`, `->first()` or anything like that. This way you can see what is going to actually execute, so you can clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

With the right relation declared being `belongToMany` between Post::class and Component::class, and `mophTo` between component and memory/processor

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('components', function(Builder $compQB) {
    $comQB->whereHasMorph(
        'componentable',
        [Processor::class],
        function (Builder $query) {
            $query->whereBetween('core_clock', [1.8, 2.4]);
        }
    )
})->whereHas('components', function(Builder $compQB) {
    $comQB->whereHasMorph(
        'componentable',
        [Memory::class],
        function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('capacity', '>=', 32);
        }
    )
})
    ->where('description',....)
    ->where('title', .....)
    ->get();
```

I dont know how the sum memory part works, but i hope this gives you at least a good hint on the structure of the query builder.

Comment: Thanks, that looked promising. However there is no relation in Post model named `components`. It must go through `Postpart` model to get components relation. Can you incorporate that into your answer please? As it stands, Laravel throws exception saying that `Call to undefined method App\Models\Post::components()`.

Comment: @dotNET Following your schema image, you have two foreign keys in postparts; one for post and one for component. That exactly how pivot able work and the nature of the relation between posts and components is many to many.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use -`>select('1')` directly.

you should use raw expression:

```
->select(DB::raw(1))
```

see [whereExists](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-exists-clauses) example.